Finding Nth earliest (oldest) date from list, date is partial string
I'm looking to get the Nth oldest date from a list of text strings. The data looks like the following:



Date




100% (05/29/2024)


100% (11/08/2022)


100% (03/28/2022)


100% (11/08/2022)


100% (10/25/2022)


0%


25% (05/29/2024)


100% (08/25/2022)


100% (10/25/2022)



The result, if N = 1, should be the oldest date or 03/28/2022. If N = 3 the result should be 10/05/2022.
I'm aware of the function SMALL() and MID() but I'm not sure how I can combine these two while also only looking for those fields that have dates. Only those that are >0% will have dates included, but only those at 100% should be evaluated.

Maybe try:
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(--REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A9,"^100% \((\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\)$")),1),"No Value")

That way you'd only pull the dates when a string starts with '100%' and follows the rest of the correct input's pattern. Here the '1' is your 'N'. Just change it as desired.

Worked for me as long as the format of the date is MM/DD/YYYY.

I have N, or the 1, linked to a cell. When I delete the value it lists all values all the way down. I don't think this will be a problem because I don't anticipate that cell to be blank but I thought I would bring this up. Thanks for the answer and for the quick response.

We can adjust that format if need be @DanCue. Thanks for the feedback.

Let me ask you the same question I asked on another answer...Let's say the data is spread across a row instead of a column? I didn't specify that in the question, but I just thought that I may need to go that route. Would this work or how would I need to change it to adapt?

TOCOL seemed to work.

@DanCue: Rather use a formula that can handle both options in that case: =IFERROR(INDEX(LARGE(--REGEXEXTRACT(D1:L1,"^100% \((\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\)$"),8)),"No Value"). Here D1:L1 is a placeholder for the horizontal array. The '8' obviously the 'N'.

I'm afraid that one didn't work. It worked with the TOCOL, as expected, on the horizontal array.

Worked for me, but obviously go with whatever works for you @DanCue. Glad your issue is solved.

Yeah. I must be doing something wrong. Neither vertical or horizontal are working. Getting No Value with either. Either way, thank you.

TOCOL actually seems to work with both.  =IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(--REGEXEXTRACT(TOCOL(A19:A),"^100% \((\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\)$")),B$18),"") and =IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(--REGEXEXTRACT(TOCOL(B31:J31),"^100% \((\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\)$")),B$18),"")

=index(sort(ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(datevalue(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A10,"[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"))))),1,true),1,1)
Change the range to reflect your data in the regextract portion of the formula (here A2:A10 for example).
The second to last number will be the Nth digit, representing oldest.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(n,B1,
 query(sort(split(A:A,"()")),"Select Col2 Where Col1=1 limit 1 offset "&n-1))



I can confirm this works. I'm just curious why LET is being used? In this case we're only using one instance of n.

Just to make it simply evident where the n factor is going in and all...

You can also use:
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(A1:A9,"()"),"where Col1=1 order by Col2"),n,2)

Change n to the number you want. For n=1, we have:

For a horizontal range, use TOCOL:
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(TOCOL(A1:I1),"()"),"where Col1=1 order by Col2"),1,2)



This solution also works. Let's say the data is spread across a row instead of a column? I didn't specify that in the question, but I just thought that I may need to go that route. Would this work or how would I need to change it to adapt?

replace A1:A9 with TOCOL(range).
